# Why useLayoutEffect can access renewed DOM data, while it fired before DOM changes painted by browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Simple React component.
SVG element with `onClick` handler.
For some reason useLayoutEffect "see" DOM changes BEFORE it applied to real DOM.
How to make it "see" actual DOM?

Here is what happens:
1 onClick handler trigger useState function and mutate color variable.
2 color variable change trigger `useLayoutEffect` and `useEffect`
3 `useLayoutEffect` holds script execution for 3 seconds
3.1 For some reason console.log show new state of HTML element. Thats strange.
4 changed DOM come to place, i.e element rendered with new color in style object.

My question:
Why `useLayoutEffect` show new element style BEFORE it actually changed?

Here is React comnponent [source](https://github.com/artemu78/webdev_test_ya_ar/blob/main/src/components/logo/index.tsx):

```
const sleep = (duration: number) => {
  let start = new Date().getTime();
  let end = start;
  while (end < start + duration) {
    end = new Date().getTime();
  }
};

const Logo = () => {
    const [color, setColor] = useState<string>("red");
    const logoRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
      console.log(`useLayoutEffect BEFORE sleep(3sec) getElementById color=${document?.getElementById("logowrapper")?.style.fill}`);
      console.log(`useLayoutEffect BEFORE sleep(3sec) logoRef color=${logoRef.current?.style.fill}`);
      sleep(3000);
      console.log(`useLayoutEffect AFTER sleep(3sec) getElementById color=${document?.getElementById("logowrapper")?.style.fill}`);
      console.log(`useLayoutEffect AFTER sleep(3sec) logoRef color=${logoRef.current?.style.fill}`);
    }, [color]);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(`useEffect color=${document?.getElementById("logowrapper")?.style.fill}`);
    }, [color]);
  
    const changeColor = () => {
      setColor((color): string => (color === "red" ? "green" : "red"));
    };
  
    return (
      <div
        onClick={() => changeColor()}
        className="App-logo"
        style={{ fill: color }}
        id="logowrapper"
        ref={logoRef}
      >
        <LogoSvg />
      </div>
    );
    // return <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" onClick={changeColor} style={{fill: 'red'}}/>
  };
```

Real life example here: https://artemu78.github.io/dropdown/ (click on react logo in the center and it will change color with 3 seconds delay)

Repo here: https://github.com/artemu78/webdev_test_ya_ar

Comment: That is the point of [`useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect), it provides the DOM that *will* be rendered to provide a chance for metrics to be taken or (not recommended) manual changes to be made before it is drawn.

Comment: @pilchard how is it possible at all?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? React has full control over the DOM (and shadow DOM) and simply calls the callback passed to `useLayoutEffect` against the recalculated DOM tree before it sends it to the screen.

Comment: Thank you @pilchard, but what means "call callback against recalculated DOM"? 
I mean in this example - useLayoutEffect show renewed color BEFORE it pained by browser, and the code address a standard `document.body`, how is it possible to make a virtual DOM respond on `document.body` requests? (i hope you understand my English)

Comment: The virtual DOM is a complete DOM tree including a `document` element that is separate from that seen on the screen at the time the `useLayoutEffect` is called. The `document` that you are querying against in the `useLayouEffect` is in the virtual DOM which will be rendered to the screen once the layoutEffect is finished.

Comment: see: [Create your own virtual DOM to understand it](https://aibolik.com/blog/create-your-own-virtual-dom-to-understand-it-part-1) for a step by step tutorial for creating your own for illustration

Comment: I don't know how exactly is it implemented in React, but you can easily do this without a VDOM too: if you synchronously block the event loop *after* you made changes to the DOM, the browser won't have a chance to repaint the page before the blocking code runs, but the DOM did change. `document.body.innerHTML = 'Hi there'; console.log(document.body.innerHTML); sleep(3000);`

Comment: Btw, never ever use a synchronous sleep in JS for anything other than testing stuff, because it freezes the entire page while it "sleeps", and also spins up the CPU like crazy. Use an async sleep like `setTimeout` or a Promise-based `sleep`.